# is it possible to make part of text box read only?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to show a default text in textbox and make it readonly.

user will be able to add text after that readonly text.

Is it possible by JS and html or css ??

[image]

The text READONLY  will be readonly and cannot be changed by user. But user can add some text after that . is it possible. I wanto post the text. so i am not going with label.i can split it into 2 . but i am just curious!!

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case? Or do you just want a blind answer?   Also what is this "READONLY WRITABLE"?

Comment: One approach is to manage the content of the textbox by monitoring key events, and prevent a fixed/"read only" part of the textbox from being deleted.

Comment: FYI: If you want to read/add the "readonly" value, just add it manually server-side. You **cannot** guarantee that the text will be uneditable, it's for the UI only. People can "hack" it very easily. You know that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var InputMask = {
init: function () {
    var divMask = document.getElementById("readonly");
    var inputField = document.getElementById("myInput");

    InputMask._input = inputField;
    InputMask._pos = 0;
    // resets the form
    inputField.value = "";

    divMask.addEventListener('click', InputMask.focusHandler, false );
    inputField.addEventListener('focus', InputMask.focusHandler, false );
    inputField.addEventListener('keydown', InputMask.keyInput, false );

},

focusHandler: function(event){
    InputMask._input.focus();

    var backup = InputMask._input.value.substr(20) || "";

    InputMask._input.value="                    " + backup;
},

keyInput: function ( event ) {
    var length_invalid = (InputMask._input.value.length == 20 ) ? true : false;
    var realString = InputMask._input.value.substr(20);
    var realLength = realString.length;

    // fix to mouse selection delete
    if ( InputMask._input.value.length < 20 ) {
        InputMask._input.value="                    ";
    }

    // backspace code = 8
    if (event.keyCode == 8 && length_invalid ) event.preventDefault();

    // left arrow key = 37
    if ( event.keyCode == 37 && (realLength + InputMask._pos) == 0 ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else if (event.keyCode == 37 && ( InputMask._pos >= (0 - realLength))) {
        InputMask._pos--;
    }

    // right arrow key = 39
    if ( event.keyCode == 39 && InputMask._pos < 0) InputMask._pos++;        

    // enter = 13
    if ( event.keyCode == 13) {
        alert ( "Input Value: ["+ InputMask._input.value.substr(20) +"]");

        // reset
        InputMask.reset();
    }
},
reset: function(){
    var field = InputMask._input;

    field.value = "";
    field.blur();
}
};

InputMask.init();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enzoferber/qd6ZV/2/)

This code uses the CSS styling, some text spacing in the input value and event handlers. I didn't write a full handling function for mouse selection, which currently lets the user select the white spaces and delete it (or even backspace it, if there is a string typed), but will insert the 20 spaces if any key is pressed and the length is < 20.

When you press the arrow keys, it will calculate where the cursor is, and based on that, let you move it or not (just simple preventDefault). And on ENTER, will display the value without the filling spaces.

The good thing about the overlapping div is that you can use different text colors, backgrounds, etc (div styling).... All you need to do is set the amout of white spaces to make it appear that the div is inside the input.

Of course this is not cross-browser, you'll have to do all the declaration checks and event handling checks on your own, but I think that's basically what you wanted, right?

Comment: I just realized that I didn't add some `if`'s to treat the UP ARROW or HOME key. Adding a `if ( event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 36 ) event.preventDefault();` after the mouse selection fix will KINDA solve it, since you'll lose the function of those keys. You'll have to make another treatmeant to put the cursor at the end of the white spaces...

Comment: And if you want to post the read-only text, just save it in a hidden input in the form. Simple JS can achieve that. So you can set both the div and the hidden input with JS! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Move the text to a normal (`<label for>`) element before the textbox and add CSS styling to make it look like the it's inside the box.

Comment: Hmmm . Then for posting that value i have to use hidden.assume the default value is current date

Comment: Problem with this is, there's no way to know how much space the "readonly text" will occupy, unless you have an idea.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: You shouldn't need to know that.

Comment: @SLaks It will cover up the actual user input. Maybe you should develop  your answer a bit more.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: That depends on how you layout the textbox.

Comment: @SLaks I think I get what you mean now.

Comment: Although I'm not sure how possible it is to make a fixed-width outer box with a variable-width side part.

Comment: @WesleyMurch   That looks nice . but the only problem i cannot post it

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Yes, but I meant a fixed-width _outer_ box.  (also, the font and line-height don't match)

Comment: @zod: You could make the read-only part a second readonly `<input>` styled to look regular.

Comment: @zod - why do you need to post the readonly part? You already know what it is, it had to come from somewhere for you to decide it was the readonly part.  Sending data to a page only to have it sent back to you (like hidden fields) is just an opportunity for tampering by the end user.

Answer (score 2):

Any true validation should be done in the backend, but you can assign a value to the textbox's value attribute.  On load this will set the `defaultValue` property of the element in the DOM.  Then, on every keyup event, you compare the text's value to that of its original value and modify it as you see fit.

If you insert text into the middle of the value, notice how it inserts the part that doesn't match and keeps the rest of the value, which you had.  This could be useful if you paste in a long string and don't want to lose the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/HdpPp/

```
var $text = $('#text');

$text.on('keyup',function(){
    // Cache some lookups
    var $this    = $(this);
    var _val     = $this.val();           
    var _dv      = $this.prop('defaultValue');
    var _len     = _dv.length;
    var _tmp     = _val.substring( 0, Math.min( $this.val().length, _len ) );
    var mismatch = { found:false, position:0 };

    // Look for character position where two strings differ
    for(var i=0,n=_tmp.length;i<n;i++)
        if ( _tmp[i] != _dv[i] ) {      // compare two characters; true=difference found
            mismatch.found = true;      // set the boolean
            mismatch.position = i;      // store the position
            break;                      // stop looking
        }

    // Original string exists, but with end characters missing
    if ( !mismatch.found && _tmp.length < _len )
        mismatch.position = _len - ( _len - _tmp.length );

    // Insert original string before the mismatch position
    if (mismatch.found || mismatch.position) {
        _val = _val.split('');
        _val.splice( mismatch.position, 0, _dv.substring(mismatch.position) );
        _val = _val.join('');
        $this.val(_val);
    }
});
```

---

The easiest way to implement this is to use CSS / label positioning, as others have already suggested.

Comment: if I type something inside `READONLY` (e.g. `s`) it looks like `READONLYsDONLY`, so your answer is not only too long and complicated but it even doesn't work

Comment: @vladkras no, that's the intended effect; however, your comment is wrong... it should have been `READONLYsONLY` (no `D` after the `s`).  Furthermore, it's not long, it's quickly typed, you could easily minimize it to something more sensible/optimal, my role is not to do the work, but to provide ***a*** solution/answer.  Thinking more, this is almost too simple, the other JS solution would be to handle keyCodes.  This doesn't even include mouse events.  Instead of curing the symptom, it'd be better to cure the answer -- why is this needed?

Comment: This is the only answer I have found that actually accounts for having the readonly text in the input value. Very useful thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just somethin I whipped up.  Hope it helps

```
 <div style="position:absolute; z-index:1; top:1px; width:270px; border:2px; border:1px 
 solid black;">type here:</div>

 <input style="position:absolute; z-index:2; top:1px; width:200px; left:70px; border:0px   
 solid black;"/>
```