# Part of text box readonly with default value

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, textbox, readonly

Can we display part of a text box to be read-only with default value?

I want to display a number preceded by two Zero's in a text box and the two zeros must not be editable.

Comment: It is possible. Can you show your code so far and a live demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: This question has already been answered! Here it is:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221114/is-it-possible-to-make-part-of-text-box-read-only

Comment: I got this, http://jsfiddle.net/Yt72H/
I have to make some modifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to make a textbox part readonly (*at least with pure css and html)* and part not. However you could do something similar to how twitter bootstrap does it, just change the background color to white to make it appear to be one input.

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
  </div>
```

**Override:**

```
.input-group { 
    width:50%;
}
.input-group .form-control {
    border-right:none;
}
.input-group .input-group-addon {
    background-color:#fff;
    border-left:none;
}
```

**Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/QJu3y/2/

**Bootstrap:**

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic

Comment: If you click on the .00 and hit backspace (thinking its part of the textbox) that causes your browser to go back. Not what a user would expect.

Comment: The .00 is not selectable, so  I don't think the user would expect to change it. Anyways, these are things which could easily be tweaked by the developer to make it more usable for their "target audience". As I understand it this question isn't about user experience. But more about how to make it display a certain way.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this.  Just check that the two zeros are at the beginning of the value each time the value is changed, and if not, add them back in.

Javascript:

```
function zOnChange()
{
    var ele = document.getElementById('zeronumber');
    var value = ele.value;
    if( value.substring(0,2)!='00' )
    {
        if( value.substring(0,1)=='0')
        {
            ele.value = '0' + value;
        }
        else
        {
            ele.value = '00' + value;
        }
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<input type='text' id='zeronumber' value='00' onChange='zOnChange()' onKeyUp='zOnChange()' />
```

I like this because unlike the other solutions, you can select the whole text box and delete it (but the 00 comes back).  And it doesn't break the End button like the pretty cool solution you've got at jsfiddle.net/Yt72H.